# UITableView with Tab Bar Controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tab bar control and I want to show table view in first tab.

In my story board I have Tab Bar view controller with Items and I put the tableview and tableview cell in it. ( I am not sure about it. Should I put them to show data in tableview or should I do it programmatically?) I am getting the data from database (there is not any problem in this side) but can not bind the data in tableview.

What is wrong in my code?

My code:

.h file

```
     @interface CategoryTabController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
    {
        DatabaseProcess *databaseProcess;
        UITableView *categoryTableView;
        NSMutableArray *categoryTableArray;

    }

.m file

@implementation CategoryTabController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    databaseProcess = [[DatabaseProcess alloc]init];

    //Get Category data to array
    categoryTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[databaseProcess getAllActiveCategory]];


    categoryTableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];

    categoryTableView.delegate = self;
    categoryTableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview: categoryTableView];


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return categoryTableArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CategoryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [categoryTableArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make categoryTableView as IBOutlet property and connect it to your table in IB. Also you must set "CategoryCell" as cell identifier in IB to 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' to work.